# Dynamic Variable name construction in JS using Lodash or ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, lodash

Instead of referring  `fields[0] fields[1]`, Someone help me to construct dynamically.

```
//fields =['string1','string2']  

createNestedSubDoc(id, body, fields) {
    return this.model.findById(id).then(doc => {
        doc[fields[0]][fields[1]].push(body)
        return doc.save()
    })
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't elegant, but I am pretty sure that this is what you're wanting to get done.

```js
// Your current code:
//fields =['string1','string2']  

//createNestedSubDoc(id, body, fields) {
//    return this.model.findById(id).then(doc => {
//        doc[fields[0]][fields[1]].push(body)
//        return doc.save()
//    })
//}

// Lodash solution.
const fields = ['string1', 'string2'];

function createNestedSubDoc(id, body, fields) {
  return this.model.findById(id)
    .then((doc) => {
      const path = _.join(fields, '.');
      const currentPathArray = _.get(doc, path, []);
    
      _.set(doc, path, _.concat(currentPathArray, [body]);
      
      return doc.save();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are doing right now:

```
// Your code pushes body to the array doc.key1.key2
// Is that the behaviour you want?
const doc = {
   key1: {
      key2: []
   }
}

const fields = ['key1', 'key2']

createNestedSubDoc(id, body, fields) {
    return this.model.findById(id).then(doc => {
        doc[fields[0]][fields[1]].push(body)
        return doc.save()
    })
}
```

If the number of fields is unknown, you can use `lodash.pick`:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

createNestedSubDoc(id, body, fields) {
  return this.model.findById(id).then(doc => {
    const arrayPropertyInDoc = _.pick(doc, fields)
      arrayPropertyInDoc.push(body)
      return doc.save()
  })
}
```

If what you are *actually* tryna do is merge a document fragment contained in `body` to a particular point in the `doc`, then push is not the right method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Josh Wulf, But don't worry about keys that are just my field names in my mongoose document. I need the fields which i refer by that index that should construct dynamically. #thanks_in_advance

Comment: Yes, and that is what your code does. What's the problem you are having? You want to get the key names from the doc itself?

Comment: Once again thanks @Josh Wulf, I think I don't clearly expose my question. The problem is There is a limit in fields. right? I want number of string to be passed through an array(fields) so that i  should construct this line `doc[fields[0]][fields[1]].push(body)` dynamically right?

Comment: It shows `arrayPropertyInDoc.push is not a function`

Comment: You console logged it to see what it is, right? `console.log(arrayPropertyInDoc)`. Debugging 101.

Comment: Thanks for your great help @Josh Wulf

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to mark it as the solution if it worked for you.